# How to change default message generated by Resharper for empty string check (null-check)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, null-check

Resharper has great feature of adding null check code for arguments. For strings it can add `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check with `ArgumentException`. Everything's fine, but I need to have Resharper generate another message, and not `Value cannot be null or whitespace` as it does by default. Instead of this, I want to have `Value cannot be null, empty, or consist only of white-space characters` message. In the `Null checking` configuration tab I didn't find anything related to string checks. Is there some other place to configure the message?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be not possible with current ReSharper version (2019.1.2).

I checked `JetBrains.ReSharper.Intentions.CSharp.dll` with `ildasm` and it seems that the strings `"Value cannot be null or whitespace."` and `"Value cannot be null or empty."` are hardcoded and not customizable.

`JetBrains.ReSharper.Intentions.CSharp.ContextActions.CheckParameters.StringParameterIsNotNullOrEmptyCheckAction`'s `get_ExceptionMessage` method:

```
.method /*06001927*/ family hidebysig specialname virtual 
        instance string  get_ExceptionMessage() cil managed
// SIG: 20 00 0E
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x82f24
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  /* 72   | (70)017EBE       */ ldstr      "Value cannot be null or empty." /* 70017EBE */
  IL_0005:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method StringParameterIsNotNullOrEmptyCheckAction::get_ExceptionMessage
```

`JetBrains.ReSharper.Intentions.CSharp.ContextActions.CheckParameters.StringParameterIsNotNullOrWhitespaceCheckAction`'s `get_ExceptionMessage` method:

```
.method /*0600192D*/ family hidebysig specialname virtual 
        instance string  get_ExceptionMessage() cil managed
// SIG: 20 00 0E
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x82f5f
  // Code size       6 (0x6)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  /* 72   | (70)017F4C       */ ldstr      "Value cannot be null or whitespace." /* 70017F4C */
  IL_0005:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method StringParameterIsNotNullOrWhitespaceCheckAction::get_ExceptionMessage
```

If this feature is important for you, then you can try and request it by filing a ticket in JetBrains' bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive reply. I've logged a ticket. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-475309